# Oracle Connection Pool is throwing ORA-00942 the first time we get a connection. This occurrs only on the first time

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, connection, pool

We have a spring boot application where we configured an Oracle Connection Pool.  The first time we extract a connection from the pool. The connection pool throws ORA-00942 table or view does not exist at Oracle.jdbc.driver.T4TTloer11.processError.

This only occurs for the first connection we extract from the pool.  Other connection extractions work.

We are using UnversalConnectionPoolManager and Oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.

I can not Share the code because my firm is blocking the stack overflow site. Also my firms security team goes crazy if we post code on blogs outside of the firm.

Comment: In most cases it occurs if you have insufficient privileges and/or incorrect datasource configuration. Also check the block size and/or quota privileges your user has.

Comment: If it was a privilege issue it would always fail when we try to get a connection.  It only fails the first time we get a connection. If the block size is an issue would it be an intermittent problem or would it continuously fail.

Comment: Hmmm. What oracle db and driver version you are using?

Comment: Is the issue resolved? If yes, how? Else see if this can help you - https://community.oracle.com/thread/2188514